# ArangoDB Creating Document leads to empty inserts

Tags: c#, .net, arangodb

I'm using "https://github.com/yojimbo87/ArangoDB-NET" in my project, trying to import data from an xml file. Debugging the code showed me that the values are inside the object, but when creating the document inside the collection, it leads to an empty insert.

Here is my createDocument method:

```
static string createDocument(ADatabase db, string collection, object dataType)
    {
        var createDocumentResult = db.Document.WaitForSync(false).Create(collection, dataType);
        string key = "";
        if (createDocumentResult.Success)
        {
            key = createDocumentResult.Value.String("_key");
        }
        return key;
    }
```

And here are my classes:

```
class Artist
{
    public int Id;
    public string Name;
    public bool Extra;
}

class ReleaseArtist
{
    public string ReleaseKey;
    public string ArtistKey;
}

class Format
{
    public string Name;
}

class ReleaseFormat
{
    public string ReleaseKey;
    public string FormatKey;
}

class Genre
{
    public string Name;
}

class ReleaseGenre
{
    public string ReleaseKey;
    public string GenreKey;
}

class Style
{
    public string Name;
}

class ReleaseStyle
{
    public string ReleaseKey;
    public string StyleKey;
}

class Track
{
    public string Position;
    public string Title;
    public string Duration;
}

class ReleaseTrack
{
    public string ReleaseKey;
    public string TrackKey;
}

class Release
{
    public int Id;
    public string Status;
    public string Title;
    public string Released;
    public string Country;
}
```

I'm creating the object and trying to get the key of that document like this:

```
 Release album = new Release { Id = releaseId, Status = releaseStatus, Title = releaseTitle, Country = releaseCountry, Released = releaseReleased };
                string releaseKey = createDocument(db, "Release", album);
```

Unfortunately, like said, when I look in the admin area of Arango-DB it shows me that the inserted objects are empty, even though in the debugger of visual studio it says me that there is valid data in the 'dataType' object!

Comment: can you have a look at whats on the wire using wireshark? Whether the content is lost in the driver?

Comment: could you give me short instruction of how to use wireshark? i just started it in the background but it didn't show anything with port 8529

Answer (score 6):

Data within your classes which you want to be stored needs to be defined as properties, e.g. therefore your `Release` class should look like this:

```
public class Release
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Released { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
}
```